How do I multithread in the MVP architectural pattern?
I am programming a desktop app for a small local hotel using python.
As is so often the case, I also have a heavy-duty process/method in the background. During that time a progressbar should pop up and fill itself. The progress bar should block any further input and serves as user information: "Data/tasks are being processed"
My issue:
I am unable to achieve both: running the heavy_load_method in the background and showing&filling the progessbar at the same time.
I assume that I implement my progressbar incorrectly for multithreading/multiprocessing.
Since my failure is possibly related to my current implementation of the MVP, some code snippets:
# main.py
# importing all modules (presenter, model and all views/formulars (including the progressbar view/form)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainwindow = Mainwindow()
    progressbar = ProgressBarPopup()
    model = Model()
    ...
    presenter = Presenter(model, mainwindow, progressbar, ...)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

# presenter.py
# imports modules required for data manipulation

class Presenter:
    def __init__(self, model, mainwindow, progressbar, ...)
        self.model = model
        self.mainwindow = mainwindow
        self.progressbar = progressbar
        ...

    def heavy_load_method(self):
        # does operations like:
        #  - getting (minor) amounts of data from form/view (related view/form method calls)
        #  - processes already cached `self.data` (via Presenter method calls)
        #  - calling and calculating data from the model/database
        #  - calling functions from imported moduls like "myfilemanagement.py"
        #  - ...

# MyProgressbar.py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QProgressBar, QDialog, QVBoxLayout, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QTimer

class ProgressBarPopup(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Progressbar")
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.Window | Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setFixedSize(300, 100)
        self.setWindowModality(Qt.ApplicationModal)
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.label = QLabel("Processing...", self)
        self.label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.progressbar = QProgressBar(self)
        self.progressbar.setRange(0, 99)
        layout.addWidget(self.progressbar)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        # Progressbar visual update timer
        self.step = 0
        self.timer = QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update_progress)

        # Progressbar exit/close timer
        self.close_timer = QTimer(self)
        self.close_timer.timeout.connect(self.close_progressbar)


    def close_progressbar(self):
        self.close_timer.stop()
        self.close()

    def update_progress(self):
        self.step += 1
        if self.step <= 98:
            self.progressbar.setValue(self.step)
        if self.step > 98:
            self.timer.stop()
            self.label.setText("This takes longer then expected.")


    def setup_progressbar_and_show(self):
        self.step = 0
        self.progressbar.setValue(self.step)
        self.timer.start(70)
        self.close_timer.start(10000)
        self.label.setText("Processing...") 
        self.show()

I have tried to multithread or multiprocess the method heavy_load_method. My previous attempts failed because I could not multithread/multiprocess the progressbar.

Do you have a reason to not use QProgressDialog? Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/63940295/51685

@AKX I assume not? I will look into it. I suspected that I was implementing my progressbar incorrectly (progressbar is passed to the presenter, so it probably is not suddenly multithreadable during runtime).

@AKX Based on your link: I have to create another class that inherits from QThread that will receive almost a full copy of the Presenter? (heavy_duty_method needs access to model/db and so on)

The MVC/MVP patterns are often not necessary when using Qt, but if a "global manager" (the controller/presenter) is actually required by the program structure, it's generally better to use it as a QObject subclass (allowing proper signal/slot features) and that is often achieved by using the QApplication itself, since it's normally the common object and there always is just one instance of it. Any "heavy duty" processing should then be delegated to a separate object (normally, a QThread) that shall never directly access the UI but only work with the data and eventually signal the results.

@musicamante Are you suggesting, that my Presenter class should inherit from QApplication? I created a Worker class very similar to stackoverflow.com/a/63940295/51685. (Copied needed modules and methods, initiliazed(constructor) with the needed data. run(self) calls the "heavy_duty_method"). It crashes on self.worker.started(self.progressDialog.show()) => TypeError: native Qt signal is not callable. I currently read up on QThread.started. What could cause this error?

The error is clear: signals are not callable, you need to connect to a signal, not call it. Also, in signal connections you pass the reference to the function, you do not call it. Change to self.worker.started.connect(self.progressDialog.show), then read more about signals and slots, for example starting from this.

@musicamante If MVC/MVP patterns are not necessary for a (in my case) desktop booking tool: Which patterns are usually applied? I chose MVC/MVP because i needed a structure to follow and was easy to expand.

@AndreasM. Programming patterns are generic conceptual structures: we're not required to follow any of them, and choosing one doesn't mean that we have to strictly follow its "known" structure. They are abstractions, simplification concepts and, fundamentally, just guidelines. While it's true that MVC/MVP are easier to follow and expand, it's also true that blindly following such patterns "because that's how it should be done" is a terrible choice. Patterns must be applied when they make sense, and as long as implementation and maintenance is profitable, which doesn't follow generic rules.

@AndreasM. For instance, the known realpython.com calculator tutorial is a perfect example: it clearly shows how MVC can be achieved with PyQt, but it also forgets to explain how such pattern is completely pointless for that basic example; interestingly enough, lots of questions here on SO were closed because of that post, because the real purpose of the post was misunderstood as a common rule to follow instead of a guideline that should've been understood before being applied to begin with.

@musicamante I think I have understood MVC&MVP. However, the examples were not coded with pyqt5.I also had experience with multithread (or actually multiprocessing) even if it was years ago. At that time it was not necessary (at least I don't remember it) to put it in a separate class(es). You just had to make sure that the calculations were actually 100% independent of each other. In addition, the load/calculations were divided so that each individual part required approximately the same computing time. Since such a splitting (thread/process) was not possible with pyqt5, this post was created

@musicamante My programming skills come mainly from "higher vocational college for computer science" and my mathematics studies (a bit java, mostly python). Ideally, I would attend a lecture or read a book to make up for my lack of modern programming skills. Unfortunately, I have not found a comprehensive work in this regard. I am therefore grateful for any help. Especially if it is very competent and clearly above my level. I will read through both of your links in full (even if I assume I already know BUT: I see i didnt know). I apologize for the quality of the current question.

I'm a bit embarrassed that it took me so long but:
Even if you intuitively believe that you have to QThread the progressbar (as this is a pyqt5 object), it is actually the other way round. heavy_duty_method must be detached from the presenter and placed in a separate QThread sub-class. An object is created from this during runtime, which can be integrated and run as below.
# presenter.py
# imports modules required for data manipulation and 'Create_Heavy_Duty_Thread' class

class Presenter:
    def __init__(self, model, mainwindow, progressbar, ...)
        self.model = model
        self.mainwindow = mainwindow
        self.progressbar = progressbar
        ...

    def prepare_for_load(self)
        if conditions_are_met:
            self.worker = Create_Heavy_Duty_Thread(self.model, invoice_dict, bookings, isClassic)
            self.worker.started.connect(self.progressbar.setup_progressbar_and_show)
            self.worker.finished.connect(self.progressbar.close_progressbar)
            self.worker.start()

class Create_Heavy_Duty_Thread(QThread):
    def __init__(self, model, invoice_dict, bookings, isClassic):
        super().__init__()
        self.model = model
        self.invoice_dict = invoice_dict
        self.bookings = bookings
        self.isClassic = isClassic

    ... # all methods needed to perform heavy_duty_method

    def heavy_duty_method(self):
        # heavy duty is done here 
        ...

    def run(self):
        self.heavy_duty_method()



Better to create a batch function processing a minor amount of the data. You can call these functions creating a thread for each of it, managing the number of them by using queue (for running rn threads) and a list (for threads to start when you will have more memory, for example). You will know when each has stoped (completed) from a function in UI main thread, and for every completed batch function you have to add the percentage of the data already processed into status bar.
Check nn_labeling function here (threading): https://github.com/ISPlatonov/Dataset-generation/blob/python/backend/HandSegmentor.py
Progress bar: https://github.com/ISPlatonov/Dataset-generation/blob/python/frontend/step%202/threshold.qml
This project is based on PySide6 (PyQt with another licence)

The smaller amount of data is the invoice header, as well as some other invoice-relevant settings. It can be customized, so I load it via: self.invoice_view.get_Invoice_Header()into theheavy_load_method`. I don't think this is causing my problem. Maybe I should have formulated the question more precise (I thought it would have been accurate enough).

My issue seems to be that my progressbar isn't multithreadable.

It doesn't have to be, as you can set the value of the progress bar to a qt value that will be updated when a signal is emitted
